# iphone response

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

i am getting response like {"nok"} .... now i want to compare this for check status of data sent or not.
this is my code

```
   NSString *responseStr = [sender responseString];


 NSLog(@"response string %@", responseStr);
if([responseStr isEqualToString:@"nok"])
 {
    NSLog(@"Hiii");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Attenzione: si è verificato un errore di richiesta del premio." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
  else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Inviato con successo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [self startIscrivity2View];

       }
```

it's always run else part...

please help me

Comment: Are you getting response from a server ? IS the response string is the following string: {"nok"} or just "nok"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe the below function of **NSString**.

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```

The above function will not check for the equality, it will tell u whether your **responseStr** contain "nok" string OR not ..

```
    NSRange myStringRange = [responseStr rangeOfString:@"nok"] ;
    if(myStringRange.location != NSNotFound )
    {
      NSLog(@"Hiii");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Attenzione: si è v      erificato un errore di richiesta del premio." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
     }
  else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Inviato con successo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [self startIscrivity2View];

       }

    }
```

Comment: @Hiren bhadreshwara :Glad to know it help you  ...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if([responseStr isEqualToString: @"nok"])
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
responseStr == @"nok"
```

with

```
[responseStr isEqualToString:@"nok"];
```

In your code, the variable is not checking if the characters in the string are the same, it is checking if they are pointing to the same location in memory.

Comment: same problem continue,, i get the response {"nok"} and i want to compare  this {"nok"}

Comment: So how about [responseStr isEqualToString:@"{nok}"]; ? or [responseStr isEqualToString:@"{\"nok\"}"];

Answer (score 0):

Try isEqualToString

```
if([responseStr isEqualToString:@"nok"]){

}
```

or compare

```
if([responseStr compare:@"nok"] == NSOrderedSame){

}
```

Never compare 2 strings using == operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
if([responseStr isEqualToString: @"{\"nok\"}"] == TRUE)
{
 ....
}
else
{
  .....
}
```

Or you can remove all exara characters from response string and then compair it.

Like -

```
NSString *str = [responseStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:responseStr];

str = [responseStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:responseStr];
str = [responseStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:responseStr];

if([responseStr isEqualToString: @"nok"] == TRUE)
{
     ....
}
else
{
      .....
}
```

Or you can try.

```
NSRange myStringRange = [responseStr rangeOfString:@"nok"] ;
if(myStringRange.location != NSNotFound )
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: hey chetan it's a if statement it's working always on TRUE condition not required compare with word TRUE

Comment: Can you put the the out put of NSLog(@"response string %@", responseStr);?

Comment: 2011-05-09 12:03:37.615 Monforte[1338:207] response string {"nok"}